# Exaile Sound Indicator Menu Integration

Tags: indicator-sound, exaile

I just made an Ubuntu 12.04 installation on a new computer, and can't figure out how I got Exaile into the sound indicator menu on my old box. Does anyone know how to do this?

Sound indicator menu with Exaile turned off on my old box:

[image: Sound indicator menu with Exaile turned off]

Sound indicator menu with Exaile turned on:

[image: Sound indicator menu with Exaile turned on]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exaile itself has to cooperate with the sound indicator menu. I found [the link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/sound-menu-indicator-plugin-exaile) I used before. Based on that post:

- Download the Exaile plugin
- Extract it to `$HOME/.local/share/exaile/plugins/`
- Open Exaile and enable "Sound Menu Indicator" via the Preference menu

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Install [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools].
2. Start **dconf-editor**.
3. Switch to `com` → `canonical` → `indicator` → `sound`.
4. Add `, 'Exaile'` to "interested-media-players":

   [image: dconf-editor]

Done.

---

Alternatively, you could run:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players "['rhythmbox', 'Exaile']"
```

Comment: That's the first time I've used the install link. Very cool.

Comment: This hasn't worked so far. Is that because I have removed rhythmbox? (Surely not.)

Comment: Take a look at `apps` → `indicators` → `sound`, too - possibly you have to add it there, also?

Comment: Thanks for the help--I figured out I have to install a plugin in Exaile itself.